# Can Xamarin Forms be run on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create an application in Xamarin Forms and run it on Windows 7?
I can't find any documentation on the Xamarin website.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't run a Xamarin.Forms app on Windows 7.
Xamarin.Forms is a UI abstraction layer for

- iOS
- Android
- Windows Phone
- Windows RT
- (in the future) Universal Windows Platform

It's not compatible to WPF or anything else for Windows Desktop applications. 
You can generally create Xamarin.Forms apps for Windows 8.0 and later by targetting WindowsRT or UWP. 
Universal Windows applications can run in a resizable window on a Windows 10 desktop PC.

Comment: Could you have a look at my most recent question? Is it impossible to debug xamarin forms on windows 7? +1.

Comment: but it is supported since 2018 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf `Xamarin.Forms support for WPF is provided by the community`

Answer (score 5):

Not directly and it will not be supported as Windows 7 is officially a legacy platform.

However.

https://github.com/jvlppm/xamarin-forms-wpf is one (orphaned?) project which was mentioned in a [Xamarin Forums thread on Forms for Desktop](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19544/xamarin-forms-for-desktops)

As Forms was made open source you can bet there will be even more projects trying to do this. Conceptually, it's a fairly straightforward remapping but I wouldn't do it unless someone hired me who had a strong need to support Windows 7.

Comment: Could you have a look at my most recent question? +1.